# How can I make that when the 3 characters are walking it will hear all the footsteps of all the 3?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem is that the AudioSource components on all the 3 have the same settings and when the characters get closer I can hear only the soldiers steps and only when stop/ended walking I can hear a bit in the end the last female character steps before she stop too.

But I want to hear them all at the same time that's why I gave the soldiers another foot steps sound clip.

This is a screenshot of one of the soldiers settings the settings are the same for all the characters. But I can hear the steps only for the two soldiers.

[image: Soldier settings]

Comment: You may upgrade the hardware. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-priority.html

Comment: just a side note, there is a "Rule of 2 and a Half" by Walter Murch stating that for more than two sources, nothing has to be in syc. in other word every point of sync is fine. https://thesounddesignprocess.com/2012/07/17/sound-design-vs-perception-ii-law-of-two-and-a-half/